# Rails button_to for Custom Name / Value Submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, button-to

In Rails is it possible to achieve an HTML output like this using [`button_to`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/button_to)?

```
<button type="submit" value="1" name="id">Type 1</button>
<button type="submit" value="2" name="id">Type 2</button>
```

What are the reasons for using `button_to` over manually entering the HTML in my form?

...

EDIT:

Perhaps I should rephrase this? Seems the better way would be to add some hidden fields to the `button_to` form. It doesn't seem like I can do this.

So what is the correct Rails solution to pass extra hidden fields to a dynamic form generated via a `button_to`? Or should I just build a form manually?

e.g. I have:

```
button_to "Download", items_path(:release_id => release), :remote => true
```

and I want to pass an extra parameter in the form POST `format => "download"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems my answer was to use the [form_tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html) helper